# Import function to decorate in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm facing a little problem with using a function to decorate in my main flask app file, when I'm importing the function. If the function is in the same file it works.

```py
# decorator.py

import functools

def validate(ClassToValidate):
    def actual_decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            # validate against ClassToValidate
            # and generate the variables `foo` and `bar`

            return func(foo, bar)

        return wrapper

    return actual_decorator
```

```py
# app.py

from decorator import validate
from flask import Flask
from schema import BaseSchema


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
@validate(BaseSchema)
def analytics(foo, bar):

    # do something with foo and bar from
    # the decorated function
    
    return ("", 204)
```

This give me the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/feawfew/Project/src/app.py", line 22, in <module>
    @validate(BaseSchema)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

If I'm having the validate function inside the `app.py` module, everything works fine.

Comment: something is screening "validate" as it is not decorator anymore, but module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my misstake. Inside `schemas.py` i had the import `from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate`. This `validate` Object is from class `module`, and i guess my `validate` function got overwritten here. Renaming solved the problem.